# Can interact with spinner items shown in dialog using onitemselectdlistener?

Tags: android, dialog, spinner, onclicklistener

I have a spinner showing categories like energy, power, etc in my units converter application. I am using 3 spinners for categories, units (from and to). From spinner I'm displaying items in dialog. Can interact with items without using dialoginterface.onclicklistener. If I use dialoginterface.onclicklistener on each item in dialog, i have to implement it for all units of category for all categories. It'll be very messy. So do i have any other alternate solution or can I implement it in a simple manner using dialoginterface.onclicklistener??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `setOnItemClickListener()` on a spinner.

Comment: Since am showing items in a dialog , still can use setOnItemClickListener() on spinner ??

Comment: I think I may have misread your question... Your spinner is completely unrelated to your issue? Show some code and I can help more. You may just need to use dialoginterface.onclicklistener with a case switch based on button id.

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 dialogInterfaces.onclicklisteners (for each category) may solve your problem